# Hover em navegação com html e css

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation-drawer, css-hover

Boas pessoal, é o seguinte, já ando atrás disso À algum tempo. Ando a tentar fazer uma box À volta dos links em `hover`, essa box vai ter de uma uma *shadow* e cantos arredondados, alguém me pode ajudar?

Desde já obrigado

```css
.main-nav {
  background-color: #2c3136;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5 0 #000;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav li a:link .main-nav li a:visited {
  padding: 8 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #5a5a5a;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <nav class="main-nav nav-js">
    <img class="logo" src="" alt="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about_us">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#search">SEARCH</a></li>
      <li><a href="#top_artists">TOP ARTISTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Exemplo de box:
https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/boombox-a-entertainment-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-template/

A box que eu pretendo é na li.

Comment: Nelson por favor edite sua pergunta colocando o código por escrito, e não imagem. De um ctrl+c e um ctrl+v aqui com o seu código html / css que vai facilitar para respondermos. Se possível coloque uma imagem do layout que vc pretende, um exemplo de como quer o Box e onde ele vai ser, na LI ou na Nav como um todo. Tente explicar melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia usar o pseudo elemento `::before` e `::after` combinado e aplicar o `background: radial-gradient(...)` (o mesmo foi feito no site) nestes elementos.

Também será necessário colocar o `position: relative;` para alinhar estes elementos acima e abaixo de cada menu, por exemplo:

```css
/*remove espaçamentos*/
.menu, .menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #1d4888;
    min-width: 800px; /* pode fixar a largura com width ou colocar uma largura minima */
    white-space: nowrap; /* impede que os menus quebrem */
    text-align: center; /* impede que os menus quebrem */
}

.menu > li {
    background-color: #1d4888;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}

.menu > li > a {
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

.menu > li > a::after,
.menu > li > a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu > li > a::after {
     top: 100%;
     background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -50%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu > li > a::before {
     top: -5px;
     background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
     background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 150%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu > li > a:hover::after,
.menu > li > a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#about_us">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#search">SEARCH</a></li>
    <li><a href="#top_artists">TOP ARTISTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.main-nav {
  background-color: #2c3136;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5 0 #000;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav li a:link .main-nav li a:visited {
  padding: 8 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav li :hover,
.main-nav li :active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #5a5a5a;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <nav class="main-nav nav-js">
    <img class="logo" src="" alt="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about_us">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#search">SEARCH</a></li>
      <li><a href="#top_artists">TOP ARTISTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: usando o "border-radius" você consegue arredondar as bordas.